# Bing Maps API refuse my connection in office internet environment

Tags: python, api, bing-maps

I can run my code and connect to Bing Map API normally in my home after disconnect vpn on my company laptop when I work from home, but after I come to office, I have to connect my company WIFI and I can't connect to Bing Map API. how to solve the issue ?
[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrNy7.png)
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjZCE.png)

```
coordinate_url=[]  
for index,row in df.iterrows():  
    url="http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?CountryRegion=" + str(row["Country Code"]) +"&adminDistrict="+str(row["State"])+"&postalCode=" + str(row['Postcode']) + "&locality=" + str(row['City']) + "&maxResults=1&key=" + Api_key  
    r = requests.get(url)  
    results = json.loads(r.content)  
    coordinate_url.append(results)
```

---

i have solve the problem ,actually it will easy, below is my code. i get the code from this paper. https://www.zyte.com/blog/python-requests-proxy/ . Actually I only need indicate the proxy_port and proxy_host of my company when I send a request to http to scrape content. Then I can use Bing Map API in my company Internet environment

```
import requests
url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"
proxy_host = "proxy.crawlera.com"
proxy_port = "8010"
proxy_auth = ":"
proxies = {
       "https": "https://{}@{}:{}/".format(proxy_auth, proxy_host, proxy_port),
       "http": "http://{}@{}:{}/".format(proxy_auth, proxy_host, proxy_port)
}
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi, i am sorry, i don't know how to add block code in there, could you click the blue color text which is contain my code screenshot ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't support connectivity or authorization problems with third party services. If someone in your office hit the API too hard and got blocklisted, there's nothing we can do about that; only Bing's operations team has the tools to identify the problem with 100% assurance, much less fix it.

Comment: i think this is not a authorization problems, only me use this key in my company. and i can use it normally in my home with vpn disconnect, no one in my company hit the API hard, only me use it. I think  only need add some code to fix this issue. Now the question is I don't know whether can run API normally in common WIFI, i know google can , but not sure whether Bing maps can also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with your company’s firewall. Go talk to your IT team and get `dev.virtualearth.net` added to the allow list.

Comment: i added my company proxy in the request.get(), than it work!